# How to cancel a running query in java persistence?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My application runs using Persistence API, Hibernate and Spring. I am using MySql DB.
There are some queries which might take a lot of time to compute, so I need a cancel button to cancel the execution of these queries.

I found out that there is a memthod java.sql.statement.cancel() which is used to cancel a query, but this can be accesssed from the statement object, how to do this from the entityManager object in Java persistence ?

Comment: I have no idea how to cancel a query but you may prefer putting a timeout with javax.persistence.query.timeout jpa property in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hibernate session objects ***[CancelQuery()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#cancelQuery())*** method.

Also if you want to automate this, you can set the query timeout. 
JPA 2 defines the javax.persistence.query.timeout hint to specify default timeout in milliseconds. (Available since Hibernate 3.5 )

JPA provides javax.persistence.query.timeout hint to specify query timeout in milliseconds. This hint can be specified in @NamedQuery or @NamedNativeQuery. It can also be specified on the Query or TypedQuery by calling the setHint method. The query timeout defined by the hint can be overridden by the setHint method.

The default query timeout can be specified for an application in persistence.xml as shown below:

```
<persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        ...
       <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" 
        value="30" />
     </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Okay, is there a method that can be called from entityManager also ?

Comment: Its hard to cancel it explicitly from EntityManager, you will need to set the timeout. That will take care of cancelling query if query doesn't get executed in specified time.

Comment: So there is no way of doing this from the Entitymanger, other than timeout ?

Comment: I get the EntityManager object in my class, can I also use HibernateSession object in the same class?

Comment: You can get the current session from session factory and call the cancelquery() method.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but my question is for quering the DB I am alreading using the EntityManager, so is it a good practice if I use both the EntityManager and the Session from hibernate to query from the same code?

Comment: You have your answer. Its not a good practice. Unfortunately no other option I can see.